# admin center powershell: The application was unable to start correctly

Tags: windows, netsh

In Windows Admin Center, when pressing PowerShell, this popup appears:

```
The application was unable to start correctly
Click OK to close the application.
```

Answer (score 0):

Whitelist winpty-agent.

In cmd:

```
netsh firewall add allowedprogram "C:\Program Files\Windows Admin Center\winpty-agent.exe" enable
```

Restart your browser.